# How can I style a Toolbar to act like an AppBar

Tags: material-ui

It looks like a Toolbar is a more customizable version of the AppBar. I would like to stick a few icons into the AppBar. I would like to replace the AppBar with a Toolbar. However, I'm currently using the lightUITheme.

It looks like Toolbars look different. Is there a way I can style a Toolbar just like an Appbar and still honor the theme so that if the theme changes, my toolbar still looks like an Appbar?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the style property of the Toolbar.
For example:

```
const toolbarStyle = {
      backgroundColor: indigo500
    }

<Toolbar style={toolbarStyle}>
  <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true}>
    <ToolbarTitle text="Options" />
    <RaisedButton onTouchTap={this.handleOpenMenu} label="Downloads" />
  </ToolbarGroup>
</Toolbar>
```

If you use the built in colours then be sure to include them too e.g.:

```
import {indigo500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
```

Comment: Did this work for anyone?  It didn't work for me.  There seems to be an extra div inside the toolbar that override this setting.